# How does IOTA detect inconsistency?

Tags: iota-network, tip-selection

For the error "com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Ledger inconsistency detected", does the inconsistency here mean local database corruption? I checked the source code of tip manager and ledgerValidator but it's quite hard to understand. How does that algorithm exactly work?

Comment: I think inconsistency means that the subtangle is invalid, as it contains an invalid transaction

Comment: I cant find it in the source code, too. Probably a former version. Did you reproduce this error on your own? How?

Comment: No, this error is from another post. See the link provided by Tobi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message was removed in April 2017. Thats the reason why you can't find it.

You can fix the issue by deleting your local database. Take a look [here](https://forum.iota.org/t/how-to-recover-from-ledger-inconsistency-detected/1127).

The code which contains this error message is following:

```
final Iterator<Map.Entry<Hash, Long>> stateIterator = state.entrySet().iterator();
        while (stateIterator.hasNext()) {

            final Map.Entry<Hash, Long> entry = stateIterator.next();
            if (entry.getValue() <= 0) {

                if (entry.getValue() < 0) {
                    log.error("Ledger inconsistency detected");
                    return null;
                }
                stateIterator.remove();
            }
        }
```

If there is more you want to know, the code can be found in [Mainnet new Release 1.1.2.2.](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/archive/1.1.2.2.tar.gz): TipsManager.java

Comment: Yep, That post is where I first knew this error. I was curious about the error, so I looked into source code. But I couldn't find the error in latest version. Then I made this post to see if anyone knew the reason and detailed algorithm to check ledger inconsistency.

Comment: I found the former code for you

Comment: Thanks! In the latest version, I found the code in Snapshot.java